# zip-file to buffer c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zip

I have to read a dat-file byte by byte from a zip-file in a char[] buffer.  The zip-file contains only one dat-file. I guess unzip chunk by chunk would be good. I am using Visual Studio 2013 with c++.

I have found zip-utils (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win), would this be ok, because its nearly 10 years old? Would Minizip be a good way? I guess zlib alone would not be enough for this use case, right?

My question is, whats the best way to do the unzipping? I have no experience with handling zip-files and would like to hear a suggestion by somebody with experience.

Thank you,

Friedrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minizip would work. Please notice that it still requires zlib source code to link with.

A zip file is not just chunks of zlib compressed content. 
It's an archive.

There is a directory header, and per element header you must decode too even if the archive only contains a single file. Typically, the header will tell you from which offset in the zip file you'll find your DAT compressed content. Then you'll likely use zlib to decode chunk by chunk starting at the given offset.

Please notice also that zip file format does not *always* imply zlib as a compressor (you can have many different compressor). If you master the code that create the zip file, it's not an issue. But if it comes from *hostile* user, then you should rely actually check the compressor used and assert it's zlib else you should deny decompressing the file because you'll not be able to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that's useful information!